# How to create a HMAC-SHA1 hash in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, hash, nestjs, hmac

I am consuming an API in my nestjs app. I am required to supply hash as part of the payload.

In the API documentation, I am supposed to do this

**Create a hash using the hash_hmac function as such**

```
computed_hash = hash_hmac("sha1", somecombinedstring, privatekey)
```

So I used cryptojs in nodejs

```
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', combinestring, privatekey);
```

When I pass hash to the endpoint, I got **Invalid Hash**

How can I create a valid hash

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this

```
  const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', privatekey)
            .update(somestringcombined)
            .digest('hex');
```